# How to break the line in a python if statement without a syntax error?

Tags: python

Let's say you have an if statement in python like this:

```
if not "string1" in item and not "string2" in item and not "string3" in item and not "string4" in item:
    doSomething(item)
```

Is there a way to break the if statement up onto multiple lines? Like this:

```
if not "string1" in item 
    and not "string2" in item 
    and not "string3 in item 
    and not "string4" in item:

    doSomething(item)
```

Is this possible? is there a different, more 'pythonic' way of making this more readable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general when you want to split up an expression onto multiple lines, use parentheses:

```
if (not "string1" in item 
    and not "string2" in item 
    and not "string3" in item 
    and not "string4" in item):
    doSomething(item)
```

This recommendation comes straight from [Python's style guide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id12):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses.

But note that in this case, you have a better option:

```
if not any(s in item for s in ("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4")):
    doSomething(item)
```

Comment: Is that second technique using lambdas?

Comment: @quakkels: I don't see any `lambda`s, so no.

Comment: I haven't looked into python lambdas at all... but I thought the `any(s in item for s....` looked a lot like c#'s `someListOfStrings.Any(s => s == "somethingtomatch")`

Comment: This does not involve lambdas, the [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function accepts an iterable and returns True if any of the elements from the iterable evaluate as true in a Boolean context.  A generator expression is used to construct the iterable `("string1" in item, "string2" in item, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just add a backslash immediately before the newlines:

```
if not "string1" in item \
    and not "string2" in item \
    and not "string3 in item \
    and not "string4" in item:

    doSomething(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

The backslashes are very ugly. If you don't want the newline anymore, you'll have to remove the backslash, whereas if you put the parenthesis there's nothing to change.

Also, in this situation you might want to consider :

```
if not ("string1" in item 
    or "string2" in item 
    or "string3" in item 
    or "string4" in item):
    doSomething(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place all the conditions of the statement within parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\` to escape the end of the line. For example:

```
$ cat foo.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def doSomething(item):
    print item

item =  "stringX"

if not "string1" in item \
    and not "string2" in item \
    and not "string3" in \
    item and not "string4" in item:
    doSomething(item)

$ ./foo.py 
stringX
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item = "hello"

if not "string1" in item \
    and not "string2" in item \
    and not "string3" in item \
    and not "string4" in item:

    print(item)
```

output: hello

Yes, backslashes do the job.
Also, your code missing one `"` after string3.